# Matplotlib: Radar Chart - axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, radar-chart, spider-chart

I am trying to plot a radar chart with 15 labels on the xaxis. The data is plotted correctly, but I am unable to define the axis labels properly.
The plot I get is as follows:
[image: acheived]

As you can see, the number of axis ticks generated is less than the number of bars generated. How can I generate equal number of ticks (and corresponding tick labels) to clearly distinguish each bar? What I want is something similar to the image shown below:
[image: required]

The code that I am currently using is as follows:

```
fig = figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)
 sample = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(15,))
 N = len(sample) 
items=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15'] 
theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/N) 
bars = ax.bar(theta, sample, width=0.4) 
ax.set_xticklabels(items)
 ax.yaxis.grid(True)
 show()
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ax.set_xticklabels` sets the text of the labels.

What you really want is to set the positions of the labels. In this case the positions are just the items of the `theta` array

```
ax.set_xticks(theta)
```

Once those ticks are set, one can of course change their labels, which in this case are just the  first `N` numbers starting at 1,

```
ax.set_xticklabels(range(1, len(theta)+1))
```

A complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,polar=True)

sample = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(15,))
N = len(sample) 

theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/N) 
bars = ax.bar(theta, sample, width=0.4)

ax.set_xticks(theta)
ax.set_xticklabels(range(1, len(theta)+1))
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that in matplotlib versions prior to 2.x, you need to center the bars to obtain the result from above

```
bars = ax.bar(theta, sample, width=0.4, align="center")
```